# CountVectorizer in Python

Tags: python, tf-idf, text-classification, countvectorizer, tfidfvectorizer

I am working on a problem in which I have to predict whether a sent email from a company is opened or not and if it is opened, I have to predict whether the recipient clicked on the given link or not.

I have a data set with the following features:

- Total links inside the emai`
- Total internal links inside the
  email
- Number of images inside the email
- Number of sections
  inside the email
- Email_body
- Email Subject

For the email body and subject I can use a **CountVectorizer** but how can I include my other feature to that sparse matrix created by said CountVectorizer.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily just concatenate these matrices and other feature columns to build one very large matrix.

However, be aware that concatenating the matrix from email body and email subject will probably create an incredibly sparse matrix. When you then add other features you might risk to "water down" your other features. This depends mostly on the algorithm you choose to use for your prediction.

In all cases you would benefit from reducing the dimensionality of the two matrices for email subject and body or directly use a different approach than CountVectorizer - for example TFIDF.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have two large sparse feature vectors (email body and subject) and also small dense feature vectors. Here is my simple suggestion:

1. (Jerome's idea) Reduce the dimension of email body and subject (via PCA, AutoEncoder, CBOW, Doc2Vec, PLSA, or LDA) so that you will end up with a dense feature vector. Then, concatenate it with other meta information.
2. I think concatenating the matrix with other features are okay. If you use a simple linear model, you can put more weights on meta information and scale down all weights learned from subject and body of the emails.

The real problem is when you use a bag-of-word representation (either term-frequency or TFIDF), your feature vector will be extremely sparse for a very short email. The model might not perform well.

By the way, I think the author information could be a good indicator whether the email will be opened or not.